# ASP.NET Required Field Validator and Compare Validator not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

None of my validators are working. Please help! Thanks in advance...

```
  if (rfvEmail.IsValid && rfvLoginName.IsValid && rfvNewPassword.IsValid
                && rfvConfirmPassword.IsValid && cvComparePasswords.IsValid)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                myDal.ClearParams();
                myDal.AddParam("@EmailAddress", txtEmail.Text);
                myDal.AddParam("@LoginName", txtLoginName.Text);
                myDal.AddParam("@NewLoginPassword", txtNewPassword.Text);
                ds = myDal.ExecuteProcedure("spResetPassword");

                lblPasswordMessage.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["result"].ToString();                
            }
```

The source code looks like this:
I've also set CausesValidation to true on Button

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    ID="rfvConfirmPassword"
                    runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Password Confirmation is required!"
                    ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword"
                    EnableClientScript="False"
                    ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                 

                <asp:CompareValidator 
                    ID="cvComparePasswords" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ControlToCompare="txtNewPassword"
                    ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword"
                    EnableClientScript="false"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    ErrorMessage="Passwords entered by you do not match!">
                </asp:CompareValidator>
```

I'm trying to validate the controls in Save button:

```
 protected void btnSavePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        rfvEmail.Validate();
        rfvLoginName.Validate();
        rfvNewPassword.Validate();
        cvComparePasswords.Validate();
        resetPassword();
      }
```

Comment: What are the definitions for the validators, i.e. the HTML portion?

Comment: Do you call `Page.Validate()` anywhere?

Comment: I tried calling Page.Validate in Save Button but it doesn't help.

Comment: Where is that initial block of C# called? Also you shouldn't need to call the `Validate()`  method on each of the controls this happens on page postback. Generally tou should use something like the following in you click handler `if(Page.IsValid){resetPassword();}`

Comment: I'm calling it in the SavePassword button click.

Comment: So its the `resetPassword()` method? What do you mean by not working? Are empty fields being counted as valid? Are completed field being considered invalid? Is the comparison proving unexpected results?

Comment: Yes, its resetPassword() method. Validation is not happening on empty/ blank fields. However, the method is working fine for completed fields.

Comment: Check the button is not disabled from server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance it appears you are going about validation the wrong way. Without further imformation it is hard to diagnose the exact problem, so I'll provide some general advice.

You should familiarise yourself with the [APS.net Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In the link provided, take note of the **Load**,**Validation** & **Postback event handling** staged. The **Validation** stage occurs automatically and will validate each of the validated controls on the page and set `Page.IsValid` as either `true` or `false`. This means you don't need to validate each control individualy.

It also important to note that **Validation**  comes *after* **Load** and *before* **Postback event handling**. It is possible to mess up the validation in the `PageLoad` event by assigning default values to controls. For this reason `!Page.IsPosback` is often used to only set controls on initial Page Load and not on subsequent postback. On postback don't reset your controls until after you've finished with them. In this instance your Click handler.

Here is how I would do it:

```
//Page Load event
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostback)
    {
        //Set Control inital page load values etc in here
    }
}


private void resetPassword()
{
   //You should investigate try/catch blocks to handle database errors better
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   myDal.ClearParams();
   myDal.AddParam("@EmailAddress", txtEmail.Text);
   myDal.AddParam("@LoginName", txtLoginName.Text);
   myDal.AddParam("@NewLoginPassword", txtNewPassword.Text);
   ds = myDal.ExecuteProcedure("spResetPassword");
   lblPasswordMessage.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["result"].ToString();          
}

protected void btnSavePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsValid) //The controls have already been validated now
    {
        resetPassword();

        //If you need to empty/reset fields on button click
        //do it here.
    }

        //Unless you want to reset them regarless of the validity
        //of the page. Then do it here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped! I'm new to C# and still learning. Thanks for taking out time to help me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help. We all have to start somewhere. The ASP.net page life cycle can take some getting used to. It is something that often trips up those getting started.